# Parsing XML with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to search for tags and attributes in a string of XML using ElementTree. Here is the string:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\n<uclassify xmlns="http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema" version="1.01">\n\t<status success="true" statusCode="2000"/>\n\t<readCalls>\n\t<classify id="thing">\n\t\t<classification textCoverage="0">\n\t\t\t<class className="Astronomy" p="0.333333"/>\n\t\t\t<class className="Biology" p="0.333333"/>\n\t\t\t<class className="Mathematics" p="0.333333"/>\n\t\t</classification>\n\t</classify>\n\t</readCalls>\n</uclassify>'
```

Prettified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<uclassify xmlns="http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema" version="1.01">
    <status success="true" statusCode="2000"/>
    <readCalls>
        <classify id="thing">
        <classification textCoverage="0">
            <class className="Astronomy" p="0.333333"/>
            <class className="Biology" p="0.333333"/>
            <class className="Mathematics" p="0.333333"/>
        </classification>
        </classify>
    </readCalls>
</uclassify>
```

I used this little code to turn the string into a searchable XML tree:

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, ElementTree
>>> tree = ElementTree(fromstring(a))
```

I thought that using `tree.find('uclassify')` would return that element/tag but it seems to return nothing. I also tried:

```
for i in tree.iter():
    print i
```

which prints something, but not what I want:

```
<Element '{http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema}uclassify' at 0x1011ec410>
<Element '{http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema}status' at 0x1011ec390>
<Element '{http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema}readCalls' at 0x1011ec450>
<Element '{http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema}classify' at 0x1011ec490>
<Element '{http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema}classification' at 0x1011ec4d0>
<Element '{http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema}class' at 0x1011ec510>
<Element '{http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema}class' at 0x1011ec550>
<Element '{http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema}class' at 0x1011ec590>
```

What's the easiest way to search for tags and attributes, such as in the BeautifulSoup module? For instance, how can I easily retrieve the className and p attributes for the class elements? I keep reading different things about lxml, xml.dom.minidom, and ElementTree, but I must be missing something because I can't seem to get what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `uclassify` is the root node so if you just print `tree` above you'll see:

```
>>> tree
<Element '{http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema}uclassify' at 0x101f56410>
```

Find only looks at the current nodes children, so `tree.find` can only find the `status` and `readCalls` tags.

Finally, the xml namespace is tweaking the names of everything so you'll need to grab xmlns and use it to build your tag names:

```
xmlns = tree.tag.split("}")[0][1:]
readCalls = tree.find('{%s}readCalls' % (xmlns,))
```

For example to get the 3 `class` tags you'd need to:

```
classify = readCalls.find('{%s}classify' % (xmlns,))
classification = classify.find('{%s}classification' %(xmlns,))
classes = classification.findall('{%s}classes'%(xmlns,))
```